# What are the best practices for locking down SSH with Ansible?

Tags: ssh, ansible

Say I have a server and I would like to do following:

- change SSH port to 33333
- disable root login
- disable password login and only allow key-based auth

I am not interested in the instructions to do these tasks. There are tons of stuff online.

My question is about the best practices.

Here are a couple of problems:

- When I change the default SSH port with a playbook, I cannot run the same playbook again on the same host. This is because I need to change the SSH port parameter in inventory file after the playbook is run once.
- Similar to above, I use root to login to system and once the root login is disabled, I need to change the 'remote_user' parameter somewhere.
- Disabling login by password causes problems similar to above.

I would also appreciate if I have some fundamental problems about my approach.

Comment: Changing the SSH port is not bast practice in the first place. What you are talking about is "security through obscurity" which is more a sarcastic joke than an actual security practice.

Comment: Yeah, you're right but that's just an additional thing I would like to do.

Answer (score 2):

I maintain a "bootstrap" playbook, separate from my other playbooks and roles, that does the initial work of installing python 2.x and python-apt or python 3.x and python3-apt (using local_action and ssh), creating users and granting sudo access, locking down root and SSH, etc. If I need to bootstrap new host(s), I run the playbook with the limit (`-l` or `--limit`) option. If I need to touch up existing hosts, e.g. add new users, I run the playbook and pass in extra variables (`-e` or `--extra-vars`) to override the SSH username and port. My tasks are parameterized such that they use sudo (or not) or become (or not) depending on the variable definitions, e.g.:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_user: root
  become: "{{ ansible_user != 'root' }}"
```

Let me know if you have further questions and I will do my best to expand upon this answer!

Answer (score 2):

Like @mwp I have playbook to init ansible. It creates special user (named 'ansible) to connect to server, add them to sudoers. This playbook is so minimal as possible.

```
---
# This playbook for prepare server for ansible.

- name: add role ansible_init
  hosts: '{{ target }}'
  remote_user: root
  roles:
    - ansible_init
```

Role 'ansible_init' is:

```
---

- name: install ansible client library
  yum: name={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items:
    - libselinux-python
    - policycoreutils-python

- name: useradd ansible
  user:
    name={{ ansible_init.ansible_user.login }}
    password={{ ansible_init.ansible_user.password }}

- name: add default ssh key for ansible user
  authorized_key:
    user={{ ansible_init.ansible_user.login }}
    key="{{ lookup('file', '{{ ansible_init.ansible_user.ssh_key_file }}') }}"
    state=present

- name: nopasswd sudo for ansible user
  lineinfile: "dest=/etc/sudoers state=present regexp='^{{ ansible_init.ansible_user.login }}' line='{{ ansible_init.ansible_user.login }} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'"
```

Other actions performed as ansible user (`remote_user = ansible` in ansible.cfg).

A number playbooks for setup servers (mail, db, web etc.) include nessesary roles, common steps separated in common playbook (which included as first step). Common playbook sets up sshd, firewalld, fail2ban, installs additional repos, server's known_hosts etc.

Typical playbook looks like:

```
# This playbook deploys 'webserver' server.

- include: init_server.yml

- name: deploy 'webserver'
  hosts: '{{ target | default("webservers") }}'
  become: true
  become_user: root
  roles:
    - git
    - nginx
...........
```

init_server.yml never called directly, from concrete playbook only.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to handle as much of this as you can prior to boot.  That is, modify the image you're booting off of so that it already has the necessary changes in place.  With Amazon this would be building a custom AMI; with other provisioning methods there will be different technology underlying it, but the principle is the same.